# Magento users/permissions web server & group

Tags: magento2, installation, permissions, group

So a prior question led me to this, I am trying to use Magento2, (very frustrating)

I have a VPS, with all the proper things for Magento2 to run.

I can install it but have huge permissions issues, because the part of the documentation I cannot understand is the part about **Put the Magento file system owner in the web server's group**

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/apache-user.html#install-update-depend-user-add2group

when I do: 
    [~]# egrep -i '^user|^group' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

I get:

```
User nobody 
Group nobody 
UserDir 
public_html 
UserDir 
disabled 
UserDir disabled
```

and I don't know how to proceed from here.

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE### I have now completely started over... I wiped the host account clean and created a new one, starting from scratch, trying to follow the install directions from magento. everything is good up until the point where I have to: **Put the Magento file system owner in the web server's group** - I'm stuck there, since my user and group are both "nobody" I don't know what to do next, is says to do this THEN install magento... so I'm just stuck here now.

Comment: `Group nobody` shows that you server run with group `nobody`

Comment: try change gorup for files with command `sudo chown -R :nobody *` from magento root

Comment: yes, and parent folder as well.

Answer (score 0):

This command `egrep -i '^user|^group' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` is to help you to grab apache user and group automatically. But you can do it also manually:

Try to open your `httpd.conf` (using some editor, for example vim).
And find this strings:

```
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User www
Group www
```

In this particular case my Apache user is www and Apache group is www.

Also from output of your command I can see that your apache user and group is **nobody** so you can proceed starting from http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/apache-user.html#install-update-depend-user-add2group (just keep in mind that you need to use user and group nobody instead apache)

If you have any questions or need more details - just let me know.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Find the Primary / web Server group **

normally webserver user can be found with root login in SSH or terminal, to understand users and groups I found these articles helpful. https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/linux-users-and-groups/ and https://www.tecmint.com/manage-users-and-groups-in-linux/

```
egrep -i '^user|^group' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

> on Centos will show user as "apache"
>   on Ubuntu will show user ad "www-data"

you can change the user name in httpd.conf file

**2. Create a new "magento_user"and put "magento_user" in webserver primary group**

```
usermod -g apache magento_user
```

-g for primary group 
-G for additional secondary group

check groups

```
groups magento_user
```

> Logout of ssh/terminal and
>
> login back
>
> restart apache server to take effect.

hope this helps